# Is there a way to programmatically export Firefox bookmarks to and from XBEL?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, xbel

Firefox allows end user to export bookmarks to the XBEL bookmark exchange format. But I would like to programmatically:

1. Export some (not all) of the bookmarks 
   and
2. Import xbel bookmarks into Firefox.

Preferably using a web language so that I can run the script from web server.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except by writing a [firefox extension](http://lifehacker.com/software/programming/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension-264490.php), I don't think you can do it. The only language that could have access to the navigator is JavaScript, and browser are designed to prevent JS from acessing them (for security purpose).